# My Delphi 7 application halts on Application.Initialize and does not return to next line

Tags: windows, delphi, operating-system, delphi-7

I have created an application on Delphi 7. my app had running fine since yesterday. I don't know what's happened yesterday which cause my application halts on Application.Initialize line in source code and does not return to next line when i trace the program. I can't run the created executable file from widows niether while the generated file does run on another machine correctly. here is the code where the compiler stops on it:

> program Info_Kiosk;
>
> uses   SysUtils,   Forms, ... (some other units) ;
>
> {$R *.res}
>
> begin
> **Application.Initialize;**
>
> Application.CreateForm(Tfrm_Main, frm_Main);

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The implementation of `TApplication.Initialize` looks like this:

```
procedure TApplication.Initialize;
begin
  if InitProc <> nil then TProcedure(InitProc);
end;
```

So, look through your code for anything that assigns to `InitProc`.

Another approach is to use your debugger to help you. Enable Debug DCUs. Then set a break point on the call to `Application.Initialize` in your .dpr file. Then step into that procedure with <kbd>F7</kbd>. Then step into the call to `InitProc` and follow that along until you reach the code that blocks.

If you are using a revision control system you can simply check out older versions of the project and use a binary search to find the commit that introduced the behaviour. If you are not using revision control, start doing so now.

Comment: Yep.Always use the debugger. Step in.

Comment: I did that and traced into the Initialize function. It seems that the application halts on a external function defined in ole32.dll and out there something goes wrong. the function name which my app ends up on it is **function CoInitialize;                  external ole32 name 'CoInitialize';*

Comment: Something very badly wrong if you app fails when calling `CoInitialize`. If I were you I would now start stripping code out, bit by bit, until you can find what other code in your program leads to this. As a first check, does a blank VCL forms app start up? Other things to think about: what did you install on that machine recently?